# Process dask dataframe by chunks of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a dask dataframe created using chunks of a certain `blocksize`:

```
df = dd.read_csv(filepath, blocksize = blocksize * 1024 * 1024)
```

I can process it in chunks like this:

```
partial_results = []
for partition in df.partitions:
    partial = trivial_func(partition[var])
    partial_results.append(partial)
result = delayed(sum)(partial_results)
```

(Here I tried using `map_partitions`, but ended up just using a `for` loop instead). Until this part everything goes ok.

Now, I need to run a function on the same data, but this function needs a to receive a certain number of rows of the dataframe instead (e.g. `rows_per_chunk=60`), is this achievable?. With pandas, I would do:

```
partial_results = []
for i in range(int(len_df/rows_per_chunk)): # I think ceil would be better if decimal
    arg_data = df.iloc[i*rows_per_chunk:(i+1)*rows_per_chunk]
    partial = not_so_trivial_func(arg_data)
    partial_results.append(partial)
result = sum(partial_results)
```

Is it possible to do something like this with dask? I know that because of lazy evaluation, it's not possible to use `iloc`, but is it possible to partition the dataframe in a different way? If not, what would be the most efficient way to achieve this with dask? The dataframe has millions of rows.

Comment: Do you need these chunks to represent consecutive rows? (that would happen in `pandas`)

Comment: Yes, the first n rows belong to a certain group and need to be processed separately from the next n rows, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repartition the dataframe along a division which defines how index values should be allocated across partitions (assuming unique index).

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(range(15), columns=['x'])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)

# there will 5 rows per partition
print(ddf.map_partitions(len).compute())

# you can see that ddf is split along these index values
print(ddf.divisions)

# change the divisions to have the desired spacing
new_divisions = (0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 14)
new_ddf = ddf.repartition(divisions=new_divisions)

# now there will be 3 rows per partition
print(new_ddf.map_partitions(len).compute())
```

If index is not known, then it's possible to create a new index (assuming that rows do not require sorting) and repartition along the computed divisions:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

# save some data into unindexed csv
num_rows = 15
df = pd.DataFrame(range(num_rows), columns=['x'])
df.to_csv('dask_test.csv', index=False)


# read from csv
ddf = dd.read_csv('dask_test.csv', blocksize=10)

# assume that rows are already ordered (so no sorting is needed)
# then can modify the index using the lengths of partitions
cumlens = ddf.map_partitions(len).compute().cumsum()

# since processing will be done on a partition-by-partition basis, save them
# individually
new_partitions = [ddf.partitions[0]]
for npart, partition in enumerate(ddf.partitions[1:].partitions):
    partition.index = partition.index + cumlens[npart]
    new_partitions.append(partition)

# this is our new ddf
ddf = dd.concat(new_partitions)

#  set divisions based on cumulative lengths
ddf.divisions = tuple([0] + cumlens.tolist())

# change the divisions to have the desired spacing
new_partition_size = 12
max_rows = cumlens.tolist()[-1]
new_divisions = list(range(0, max_rows, new_partition_size))
if new_divisions[-1]<max_rows:
    new_divisions.append(max_rows)
new_ddf = ddf.repartition(divisions=new_divisions)

# now there will be desired rows per partition
print(new_ddf.map_partitions(len).compute())
```

Comment: Hi @SultanOrazbayev, I tried your solution and your code works, but not for my case. The problem is that with the amount of data I have, I can't create a Pandas dataframe first.

Comment: I get `left side of old and new divisions are different`, because `ddf.divisions` returns a tuple of just `None`.

Comment: I see, are you loading from parquet or csv? It looks like your original data is not indexed.

Comment: I'm loading from CSV, and indeed, my data is not indexed. Does `dask` need indexed data always?

Comment: Index is needed for some operations, not all. Please see the updated example. I hope that works.